# How do I include eps files using XeLaTeX?

Tags: graphics, xetex, eps

According to everything I can find on Google, eps files in `xelatex` should work out-of-the-box. But that's not what I'm seeing (using TeX Live 2010 on Arch Linux). Consider the following simple input:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\includegraphics{flower.eps}

Some more text.
\end{document}
```

I put this into a `.tex` file and place it in the same directory as an EPS file called "`flower.eps`". Now, if I run `xelatex`, it outputs a pdf file, but the eps file doesn't appear (although space is reserved for it). On the other hand, latex+dvips works just fine.

Edit: I should mention that `pdflatex` works if I add `\includepackage{epstopdf}`. But that doesn't help for `xelatex`.

There's a related question[1], but it doesn't apply in this case because the solution was to apply the patch here[2], but it's already there in my TeX installation. Does anyone have other ideas?

[1] [can't \includegraphics eps files anymore with xelatex (used to work fine)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/cant-includegraphics-eps-files-anymore-with-xelatex-used-to-work-fine)

[2] http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=485071

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem where my output PDF would have a space reserved for the graphic, but nothing more. In my case it was caused by not having Ghostscript installed, which is necessary since `xelatex` supports EPS by converting it to PDF in the background via Ghostscript.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my used files for a working xelatex run (I used only the tiger.eps):

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2010)
   restricted \write18 enabled.

 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
   xetex.def    2009/11/22 v0.94 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

   tiger.eps    Graphic file (type eps)
 ***********
```

you can get the list with `\listfiles` in your preamble

Comment: Thanks, I got exactly the same list of files and versions. Actually, if I try including tiger.eps, then it works! So it seems that xetex is having trouble with my eps file (although every other piece of software I throw at it has no trouble...)

Comment: Ok, so I can confirm that the problem is with the eps to pdf conversion step: I got my eps file to show up by editing /etc/texmf/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg and replacing the line that starts 'D "rungs ...' with 'D "epstopdf -o=%o %i"'. Now the eps shows up, but it is positioned wrongly (ie. differently than if I do latex+dvips). Maybe I can get this all to work by just finding the right conversion tool...

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage[xetex]{graphicx}
```

Would this make any difference?

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything...