# Unable to load picture or PDF file

Tags: graphics, file-lookup

XeLaTeX has stopped including `.eps` files in my document. I get errors such as:

```
! Unable to load picture or PDF file './images/deBuitleir.fig4.eps'.
```

The image file is there, I double-checked.

**History:** Inclusion of `.eps` images worked fine until I did a "safe-upgrade" on Debian. Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/cant-includegraphics-eps-files-anymore-with-xelatex-used-to-work-fine) and [this](http://osdir.com/ml/debian-bugs-dist/2010-01/msg00752.html), it seems to be a regression of an old Debian bug. Since I couldn't find a patch that fixed the problem, I removed all TeX and XeTeX packages on my Debian system and installed TeX Live from [source](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). I then updated my path. Unfortunately, the error is still occurring, even though I have a "plain vanilla" TeX Live installation.

I really really don't want to convert all of my `.eps` files to another format. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Figure 1

\includegraphics[scale=0.5,keepaspectratio=true]{./images/deBuitleir.fig1.eps}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post a MWE (Minimum Working Example) and .eps file to check where is the mistake. Maybe is path of figures is wrong or try changing the figure to the latex source folder

Comment: Maybe it is trying to read `fig4` as the file extension.

Comment: That was the problem! I forgot that I also had to rename the images to satisfy the editor's naming convention.

Comment: Forgot to say: When I changed the first "." to an underscore, it worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your file has two dots, so LaTeX sees it as `.fig4.eps` - which is an unknown graphics file type.

Add `\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}`

See also [\includegraphics: Dots in filename](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10574/5763)